# How to create a new object which has a list structure as attribute?

Tags: java, list, object, linked-list

Let there are City objects such as

```
class City {
  private String name;
  private String code;

  //construction
}
```

also there are Flight objects such as

```
class Flight {
  private List<City> ports;
  private Number distance;

  public Flight(List<City> ports, Number distance) {
      this.ports = ports;
      this.distance = distance;
  }
}
```

How can I put the cities coming from user via Scanner into my list? I mean, I will ask to user what is source and destination info and user will input.

e.g.

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
....
Flight newFlight = new Flight(ports , distance)
```

How can I get the ports information from user? That's my real question, not create a list!

Comment: `List<Flight> listOfFlight = new LinkedList<City>();` - I will call a doctor

Comment: This code wouldn't even compile....

Comment: This question shows a lack of research into the problem at hand.

Comment: "ports" information should be obtained from user. I am stuck with it. ShouId I copy all my code and paste it? No.

Comment: You can not put City to a List of Flight **Unless** City **extends** or **implements** Flight

Comment: @Razib That's not what the OP wants. The OP wants an entirely new list to store `Flight`s.

Comment: Ohh sure here the term List is redundent/error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a bean what holds your attributes, let's call it Fligth and create a list from this Flight class ex:

List f = new ArrayList();

Then you can put it in the list some Flight object

f.add(new Flight());